# Maximum distance of a point from a triangle

Tags: trigonometry

Consider the triangle in the plane whose vertices are in $A=(0,1)$, $B=(0,0)$ and $C=(2,0)$. Distance of the point $P=(-1,0)$ from the triangle cannot happen if the target point $T$ is on $AB$ or $BC$ (excluding the limit point $B$) because geometrically points on $AC$ has more distance to $P$. Consider a point $Q$ on $BC$ and let $x$ be the length of $CQ$. Then square of $PT$ is $PT^2 = TQ^2 + PQ^2 = (\frac12 x)^2 + (3-x)^2$ and differentiating $PT^2$ and equating to zero gives $x=2.4$ which is geometrically wrong! The book say answer is $T=C$ that is in my solution I must reach at $x=0$ but I couldn't. Please help!

Comment: Your expression for $PT^2$ is not even close to correct.

Comment: @amd, why?? height is 1/2 of x since height of triangle is 1 and base is 2.

Comment: $BC$ is a segment of the $x$-axis, so $y=0$ for every point on it. $P$ also lies on the $x$-axis. The distance $PT$ is simply $x+1$.

Comment: @amd, I edit. x is distance from B. And T is a point on hypotenuse

Comment: This changes nothing. How does $T$ relate to $Q$, then?

Comment: @amd, TQ is perpendicular to BC

Comment: @amd, I am sorry, I found out my mistake. But still question remains unsolved

Comment: $T$ can’t be on $AC$ either, for the same reasons that you’ve rejected $AB$ and $BC$: every point on $AC$ is at least as far from $P$ as are points on the other two line segments.

Comment: Be that as it may, your expression for $PT^2$ is still incorrect. Your overall approach seems flawed as well: you’re going to find the point on the _line_ $AC$, but that point might be outside of the triangle, so you need to also consider the distances to the endpoints.

Comment: x = 2.4 is a minimum value, and also where dy/dx = 0, of the function not a maximum . The local maximum for this domain is at x = 0 and doesn't need any calculus.

Comment: @PhilH, x=2.4 doesn't belong to the triangle! (0,0) on the triangle corresponding to x=2 is the minimum distance.

Comment: @Edi Yes, the poster calculated an x for a minimum PT outside of the range of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $T \in AC$ then $T = tA+ (1-t) C = (2-2t, t)$ where $t\in [0,1]$. Hence the distance (squared) from $P$ is
$$
f(t) = \|T-P\|^2 = (3-2t)^2 + t^2
$$
Then, $f'(t) = 2(3-2t)(-2) + 2t = -12 + 10t$ which implies that $f$ is strictly decreasing for $t\in [0,1]$. It follows that its maximum is at $t=0$. Therefore, $T=C$ and $f(0) = 9$.

For the other two segments you can do the same and compare the 3 maximal distances to conclude that the point $C$ is the desired one.

Comment: Am I right: $f'(t)=0$ implies $t=1.2$ which is on AC-extended means that gives minimum of distance between P and AC-extended?

Comment: Yes. And for the point $T$ to fall in the segment we need $t\in [0,1]$.

Comment: Also note that $f$ is a quadratic function and you can avoid derivatives using the geometry of the parabola.